# Magento 2 Bundle product option Type Checkbox quantity user defined Quaqntity

Tags: magento2bundleproduct

Is there any way to set/show quantity box on Bundle product Option type Checkbox like Radio Button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used https://github.com/Itonomy/magento2-bundle-products-change-qty This code and modify as per my requirement.

There is an error in edit cart page. I am looking into it for fix that issue.